# I want a regex to filter some nonzero value

Tags: regex

I want a regex , filter exitcode  Between the string  "sqlcode:" "sqlerrml"  nonzero value 。

sample text:

```
sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1234   sqlerrml: 0
```

Comment: too difficult to comprehend

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\bsqlcode: ((-)?[1-9]([0-9]*)) sqlerrml:
```

IE:

- Wordbreak
- `sqlcode:`
- optional `-`
- character 1-9
- zero or more other digits
- `sqlerrml:`

You can probably use fewer brackets.

Note filtering like this with a regexp is not a good idea. Parse the string properly (with a regexp if you must) and check the value.